# How do I use a composite key for a one to many relationship in Code First EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF Code First.

I need two tables, `LedgerCategories` and `LedgerSubCategories` with a one-to-many relationship (Categories -> SubCategories), with the keys in each being codes (strings) - i.e. `LedgerCategoryCode` and `LedgerSubCategoryCode` respectively.  However, I need to allow the SubCategoryCode values to be the same for different Categories.

E.g. CategoryCode = REHAB, SubCategoryCodes = MATL, CONTR, and FEES; and CategoryCode = MAINT, SubCategoryCodes = MATL, CONTR, and FEES.

I'm thinking I need to use a composite key and include both the CategoryCode and SubCategoryCode fields in the LedgerSubCategories table.  Currently I have:

```
public class LedgerCategory
{
  [Key]
  public string LedgerCategoryCode { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public List<LedgerSubCategory> LedgerSubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class LedgerSubCategory
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public string LedgerCategoryCode { get; set; }
  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public string LedgerSubCategoryCode { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am seeding these tables using only instances of the `LedgerCategory` class, having each contain a List of appropriately instantiated `LedgerSubCategory` classes.  This appears to both set up the DB schema correctly (in my perception), and populate both tables appropriately.

But, when I reinstantiate a simple List of `LedgerCategory`, i.e.

```
using (var db = new BusinessLedgerDBContext())
{
  var LedgerCategories = db.LedgerCategories.ToList();
}
```

The `LedgerCategory` instances don't contain their respective List of associated `LedgerSubCategory` instances.

I am trying to avoid, what seems like a kludge, to introduce a unique number or Guid ID field in `LedgerSubCategories` as a PK and just index off the other Code fields.  I haven't tried this, but I'm not sure it would cause any different results for reinstantiating the `LedgerCategories` and getting associated `LedgerSubCategories`.

Any advice on how to do this appropriately and get proper results is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To, I suppose, answer my own question, I have found that overriding OnModelCreating() in the respective DbContext with Fluent API to establish the one to many relationship and foreign key when the Code First framework establishes the desired DB Schema.  There appears no other way to do this, such as with Attributes.  By many accounts of others, including MSDN, Fluent API appears to be what is needed.  However, that has led me to a new issue, or set of issues, which I've posed as a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516733).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // Configures the one-many relationship between Categories and 
  //   SubCategories, and established the Foreign Key in SubCategories
  modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasMany<SubCategory>(c => c.SubCategories)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Category)
    .HasForeignKey<string>(s => s.CategoryCode);
}
```