# Reinstantiating EF classes with one-to-many relationship and compound key of strings

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, compound-key

I have the following EF Code First classes, which appear to be working to a point.  I also have Initialization code that seeds these tables with data from elsewhere that is lengthy, and seems (I hope) inconsequential to my question.  Or at the least when I seed manually I see the same behavior problem.

Note, that these tables use strings as their primary keys, and not ID's.  Also note that the SubCategory table has a compound primary key that includes the parent table, Category's primary key, CategoryCode.  This is, perhaps, old school, ISAMish, but it is what I have to work with, and is otherwise logical.

```
public class Category
{
  [Key]
  public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public List<SubCategory> Sub Categories { get; set; }

  public Category()
  {
    this.SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
  }
}

public class SubCategory
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public string SubCategoryCode { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public Category Category { get; set; }

  public SubCategory() { }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // Configures the one-many relationship between Categories and 
  //   SubCategories, and established the Foreign Key in SubCategories
  modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasMany<SubCategory>(c => c.SubCategories)
    .WithRequired(s => s.Category)
    .HasForeignKey<string>(s => s.CategoryCode);
}
```

This structure allows the same SubCategoryCode, say "CONTR" to be used more than once for different CategoryCodes, such as "REHAB" and "MAINT".  A sample of data looks like this:

```
Categories

CategoryCode    Description
==================  =========================
BANK    Costs of banking fees and expenses
FUND    Funding Loans/Pmnts
INSUR   Property Insurance
MAINT   Maintenance Expenses
REHAB   Rehabilitation & Renovation Expenses

SubCategories

CategoryCode    SubCategoryCode Description
==================  =====================   ===========
FUND    LOAN    Monies borrowed to Entity
FUND    PMNT    Monies paid back by Entity
INSUR   BUILD   Builders Risk policy, including liability
INSUR   LANDL   Landlord policy, including liability
INSUR   MISC    Miscellaneous/Other
MAINT   CONTR   Contractor invoices, (labor, Materials, fees)
MAINT   MATL    Materials & Tooling
REHAB   CONTR   Contractor invoices, (labor, Materials, fees)
REHAB   MATL    Materials & Tooling
```

Note that I seemed to need to specify a default constructor to add instantiation of the List member, or this property ends up being null in instantiated Category classes.

Also note that I wish to have both classes include references to each other - i.e., Category has a List member to hold its constituent SubCategory data, and SubCategory has a Category member to hold a reference to its parent.

It is here that I have the greatest issue.  If I just execute the following, I get List of populated Category classes; however, each of those objects' List of SubCategory objects is empty (not null, but there with 0 items).  Now, before we blame the default constructor establishing the empty List here, note that without that code each of the Category instances contain a Null reference to their SubCategory List.

```
using (var db = new BusinessDBContext())
{
  var Categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryCode == "FUND").ToList();
}
```

But, if I add instantiating a List of SubCategory, the Category's in the List of Category will now have populated lists of SubCategory's within.  They aren't there until I instantiate the SubCategories.  And, it doesn't seem to matter if that happens before or after the query for Categories.

```
using (var db = new BusinessDBContext())
{
  var Categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryCode == "FUND").ToList();
  var SubCategories = db.SubCategories.Where(s => s.CategoryCode == "FUND").ToList();
}
```

What am I missing, or otherwise misunderstanding?

Comment: use `include` method for getting related objects: `db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryCode == "FUND").Include(x => x.SubCategories ).ToList();`

Comment: Ok, that would seem to get the results I desire; however, it seems a kludge, in that my query needs to know the internals of my class.  It also doesn't explain why this "include" otherwise happens automatically (as I believe it is supposed to) after I do a second query for SubCategories.  Is this "fix" really what EF intended?

Comment: this is eager loading when you use `virtual` in navigation property you enable lazy loading:

Comment: `public virtual List<SubCategory> Sub Categories { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `SubCategories` is null or with 0 item because you don't include this relation that it is Eager loading. if you want to use lazy loading you can use `virtual` keyword in your navigation property:

Lazy Loading:

```
public virtual List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
```

Eager Loading:

```
db.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryCode == "FUND").Include(x => x.SubCategories ).ToList();
```

[Read More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: I think I understand the issue(s) here.  The msdn reference was helpful as well.  My desire for automaticness still struggles here as Lazy loading  seems like it provides for automaticness, but can cause an unwanted query of all relationships, rather than just having a way to do automatically what the .Include() would do (Eager loading).

Comment: Perhaps, for others, I can elaborate on what I've just learned.  When not using virtual (or otherwise lazy loading off) the .Include() in the query will go that deep only (in my case SubCategories).  Putting virtual everywhere would make everything load automatically, everywhere.  Consider a large DB hierarchy, where all tables relate somehow (not so unusual), and you do a query just to get a list of the top most table's records.  Well, all of those records would have relationships, as would those, and so on.  Resulting in a large query with a heavy result for when a small result was desired.