# PgAdmin Import/Export did not keep foreign keys with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I am including a bunch information but feel free to skip the heading "The Problem" to read the actual issue.

### Introduction

In my local database, I built out a schema of tables and populated them with data.

Basic flow:

**FORMS** table has a one-to-many relationship with the **QUESTIONS** table

**QUESTIONS** has a one-to-many relationship with the **ANSWERS** table.

The **QUESTIONS** table references the **FORMS** table with a *FormId*.

The **ANSWERS** table references the **QUESTIONS** with a *QuestionId*

Here is the code for the **FORMS** and **QUESTIONS** table.

```
public class AppointmentForm
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public List<AppointmentQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class AppointmentQuestion
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public virtual AppointmentForm Form { get; set; }
    public long FormId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool? Required { get; set; } = false;
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AppointmentAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

So, I used PostMan to populate my local database.

Now, this worked out because everything was referenced and maintained with the Entity Framework.

I wrote the code you will see below to send this JSON structure to the client.

```
{
    "forms": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "formName": "Inclusion",
            "order": 1,
            "questions": [1, 2]
        }
    ],
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "formId": 1,
            "order": 1,
            "required": true,
            "question": "Are you able to go for a walk of at least 15 minutes?",
            "answers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
    ],
    "answers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "questionId": 1,
            "typeId": 2,
            "label": "Unable to do",
            "order": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "questionId": 1,
            "typeId": 2,
            "label": "Without much difficulty",
            "order": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "questionId": 1,
            "typeId": 2,
            "label": "With some difficulty",
            "order": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "questionId": 1,
            "typeId": 2,
            "label": "With a little difficulty",
            "order": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "questionId": 1,
            "typeId": 2,
            "label": "Without any difficulty",
            "order": 5
        }
    ],
    "types": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "Manual enter"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "Multiple choice"
        }
    ]
}
```

To create this, I would use the following script (or else everything would have been nested)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetModelNormalized()
{
    AppointmentModelNormalized Model = new AppointmentModelNormalized();
    List<AppointmentForm> Forms = await _formManager.GetAppointmentFormsAsync();
    List<AppointmentAnswerType> Types = await _typeManager.GetAppointmentAnswerTypesAsync();

    foreach(AppointmentForm f in Forms)
    {
        AppointmentFormReference _f = new AppointmentFormReference() {
            Id = f.Id,
            FormName = f.FormName,
            Order = f.Order
        };
        foreach(AppointmentQuestion q in f.Questions)
        {
            _f.Questions.Add(q.Id);
            AppointmentQuestionReference _q = new AppointmentQuestionReference()
            {
                Id = q.Id,
                Question = q.Question,
                FormId = q.FormId,
                Order = q.Order,
                Required = q.Required
            };
            foreach(AppointmentAnswer a in q.Answers)
            {
                _q.Answers.Add(a.Id);
                AppointmentAnswerReference _a = new AppointmentAnswerReference()
                {
                    Id = a.Id,
                    Label = a.Label,
                    Order = a.Order,
                    QuestionId = a.QuestionId,
                    TypeId = a.TypeId
                };
                Model.Answers.Add(_a);
            }
            Model.Questions.Add(_q);
        }
        Model.Forms.Add(_f);
    }
    Model.Types = Types;
    return Ok(Model);
}
```

In my local env, this all worked perfectly.

### The Problem

When I went to test QA, I exported my data using PgAdmin4 and then imported the csv file into the QA database.

Now, the line of code with `foreach(AppointmentQuestion q in f.Questions)` does not work because the FK did not get transferred with the Export/Import.

I do not understand why this happened because the FKs are all the same.

Is there a better way to export and import the data that will keep the FK relationship?

If necessary, I can grab all the questions and answers like I am grabbing the Forms. `List<AppointmentForm> Forms = await _formManager.GetAppointmentFormsAsync();`

But doesn't linq do that for me? I mean that is the point of a virtual method? It gets created when it gets called, I think so at least. Should I write custom getter and setters?

Attached is the stack trace of the exception. It is a `NullReferenceException`.

[image: This is the NullReferenceException Stack trace]

[image: This is the data in the QA database, it is there.]

Comment: `f.Questions` is null?

Comment: That’s the exception being thrown, but I know it is the db. In my local, when I call the virtual method for questions, it grabs all the questions with the matching fk. But in my QA, it is not grabbing them. I can put all the questions into a List and get them that way but I would prefer to use the virtual method

Comment: please put the exception message in your question, this issue isn't clarified for me.

Comment: I did just notice that ‘List<AppointmentQuestion>’ is not a virtual method. This might be part of the problem... but I cannot debug until I get back into work tomorrow :/

Comment: I will throw it up in the morning. Thank you.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh I added the image of the stack trace and some entries in the QA DB to show that they are there and the FormId is not null

Comment: I want to see this method `GetAppointmentFormsAsync()` codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167741/discussion-between-soheil-alizadeh-and-christian4423).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't include your related object use following code and for more info read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518205/6823285)

```
_context.AppointmentForms.Include(x => x.Questions ).Include(x => x.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers)).ToListAsync();
```

Edit from Christian4423:

I was able to get this to do the same thing with the syntax.

```
List<AppointmentForm> Forms = await _context.AppointmentForms
                .Include("Questions.Answers")
                .ToListAsync();
```